# Data manipulation for Instgram API with Ajax and JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Im trying to retrieve users from Instagram API whose names contain the certain word from a JSON file , by using this jQuery

I had to make a PHP file as a server in my local host i named it ' get_info.php' and it return an Array of elements
but for some reason I can't seem to display the output after manuplating the data  :(
I'm new to Ajax and JSON, could you possibly help me find the error in my code?

here's my JavaScript

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" >

//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e) {
        try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    var jsonObj ;
    var q = document.getElementById('keyword').value;


    ajaxRequest.open('POST', 'get_info.php?keyword='+ q , true);
    // callback function to handle the server response
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if ((ajaxRequest.status >= 200 && ajaxRequest.status < 300) || ajaxRequest.status === 304) {
                var jsonObj = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                jsonStr = JSON.parse( jsonObj );

            }
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url:'get_info.php',
                data: { keyword: q },
                success: function(jsonStr) {
                    $.each( jsonStr.data , function(index, element) {
                        var res ;
                        res += '<img src="'+element.username+'"/>';
                        res += '<img src="'+element.profile_picture+'"/>';
                    });

                    $("#photos").html(res);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

The HTML only has these tags.

```
<form id="form" method="POST" onclick="ajaxFunction();" >
    <input  value="" id="keyword"  type="text"  required>
    <input   value="search" id="submit"   type="submit" >
</form>

 <div id="photos">  </div>
```

Comment: Since you are using jquery, you don't have to fight with native javascript ajax request. Your below jquery ajax request itself looks ok.

Comment: Hi please don't put your client id details in code. please delete it

Comment: Oopss I totally forgot *-*

Comment: So does it work on your local host? :/

Comment: HI, actually it is a problem from PHP code. You are getting multiple slashes from the result it should not be that way. It is not json

Comment: The request should not contain client_id, it should contain access_token `"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=".$keyword."&access_token=".$token;`

Comment: Check this link http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search

Comment: thank youuu it worked ,but whenever I search for a user I get all the information including the meta so when I write ( jsonStr.data) i get (undefined).. how can I get only the data out from the array?

Comment: Yes, just console.log the returned json. Parse accordingly. If my answer helped you, then you can accept my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for ur help, i didnt need to parse it I wrote datatype: 'json' on my old query and it worked just fine.

Comment: Cool, even the returned data is `json` you need to manipulate it to make it available in `#photos`. This is what i meant it as `parse`. Anyway glad you are happy. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid confusion, jquery ajax is enough

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var q = document.getElementById('keyword').value;

$("#submit").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url:'get_info.php',
data: { keyword: q },
success: function(jsonStr) {
var element = jsonStr.data;
  var res ;  
for(var i = 0; i<element.length;i++) {

res += '<img src="'+element[i].username+'"/>';
res += '<img src="'+element[i].profile_picture+'"/>';

}

$("#photos").html(res);
}

});

});

});
</script>
```

Remove the onclick from form

```
<form id="form" method="POST" >
<input  value="" id="keyword"  type="text"  required>
<input   value="search" id="submit"   type="submit" >
</form>


 <div id="photos">  </div>
```

Check and let me know what you are getting in the console

Comment: I think the error has something to do with the library im using, you think I should change it ? <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">

Comment: and when I remove it I get this from the console   Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (anonymous function) :/

Comment: remove the previous version of library and include this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: now I got this erro -- TypeError: element is undefined

Comment: did you place your script at the end of document? after the form?

Comment: what is the value you have given in keyword?Are you giving correct values

Comment: yea i'm entering a valid username and it suppuse to show all the usernames that are quite similar

Comment: So you are getting the correct response. from data `jsonStr.data` after ajax call, the problem is only on appending data to `#photos`. Are we clear?

Comment: I am not sure. If you are okay to send me the php code. I'll do all things from my localhost and send you the correct code. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Rajesh I really appreciate your help, I posted the PHP code in comment below.

Comment: My apology in advanced for troubling you I kinda need to know as fast as possible i'm stuck :( , And thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Get data from instagram api
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
if(!isset($_GET['count'])) $count = 20;
else $count = $_GET['count'];

//Query need client_id or access_token
$query = array(
'client_id' => '',
'count'     => $count
);
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q='.$keyword.'&'.http_build_query($query);

try {
$curl_connection = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Data are stored in $data
$data = curl_exec($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);
echo $data;
} catch(Exception $e) {
return $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```